# Dragon Age can't use my mount in haven?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

OK so, the first place I really started questing was In the hinterlands. While I was there one of the first things I did was do the farm quests and got the free mount, and I've been riding around happily ever since. But then I decided to check out haven properly. Anyway, when I'm in Haven and I open my radial menu, the horse icon is still there, but has gone dark and when I press it nothing happens! Then when I go back to the hinterlands it works normaly again. Is there a reason why I can't use my mount in Haven?

Comment: I believe it is impossible to use mount in Haven and Skyhold. It's a normal game behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is impossible to use mount in Haven and Skyhold. It's a normal game behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think the horse by the forge/armory is yours, and that's why you can't mount when you open the radial menu. Your horse is in it's little enclosure, kind of like for chill time, so you can't ride it while you're in Haven.